# Can I use OwinContext to share data across single ASP.NET MVC5 application?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, owin

I'd like to have specific static data (site menu DTO in particular) shared across all application requests. In the old `system.web.dll` days, that would be adding data in `Application_Start` into `HttpContent.Current.Application[]` dictionary. I'm sure very similar can be achieved with Owin / OwinContext but cannot find the easy way how to add it / access it. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2):

The `Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin` library contains the class `OwinContextExtensions` which has the following methods:

```
public static T Get<T>(this IOwinContext context)
{
  if (context == null)
  {
    throw new ArgumentNullException("context");
  }
  return context.Get<T>(OwinContextExtensions.GetKey(typeof(T)));    
}


public static T Set<T>(this IOwinContext context, T value)
{
  if (context == null)
  {
    throw new ArgumentNullException("context");
  }
  return context.Set<T>(OwinContextExtensions.GetKey(typeof(T)), value);
}
```

I'm pretty sure you can use these to set and get values stored in the `OwinContext`.  Notice that the key name of the object stored in the context is the type, so for collections you should create a concrete type for the unique name:

```
public MyDictionary : Dictionary<string, int>
{
}

var myDic = new MyDictionary();

var context = HttpContext.GetOwinContext();

context.Set(myDic);

var myDic2 = context.Get<MyDictionary>();
```